# No earned badge notification for cleanup badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On Sep 19 at 11:30 I got awarded with the clean-up badge. But I did not get a notification about it.

[image]

Did the badge clean-up it's own message as well? Or is this a bug of sorts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behaviour.

Back in very old days, [you were notified of everything that happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96955) until it got annoying to people so it was turned off. The turning-off message by [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) reads:

> We're also hiding several badge notifications based on if you're associated ("veteran") or not (the clutter ones like [autobiographer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer) that you get immediately as well).

You can also find a [list of badges that aren’t hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391) over at meta.SE. That post (by [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha)) also includes a definition of *veteran:*

> On real child metas (that excludes Meta Stack Exchange), you're always considered a veteran; on all other sites, you're considered a veteran if you have received the association bonus, i.e. you have 200 rep somewhere.

By checking your profile, you have 200 reputation on at least three different sites. Thus, you are considered a veteran across the entire network. The only bronze badges you will still be seeing are those mentioned in the list:

> - Nice Answer
> - Nice Question
> - Caucus
> - Excavator
> - Mortarboard
> - Popular Question
> - Proofreader
> - Revival
> - Synonymizer
> - Tumbleweed
> - Vox Populi
> - Announcer
> - Precognitive
> - Curious
> - any tag-based bronze badge